# Labeling method for Openlayers 4

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm not an expert in web development. I made a webmap using Openlayers 4 and I have a problem with the labeling for complex vectorial features.

I want to show a label of a road that be a part of specific group.

The webmap model is [HERE](https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/a30bdf442a34b50017bb53dea6a6b986) and the GeoJson line vector is [HERE](https://gist.github.com/MaxDragonheart/fd43a1d40fab425650b614dcbbf22b3b).

When I use this code(the webmap model) I receive this error from FireFox and Chrome:

> ReferenceError: style is not defined[Learn More] test.html:37:43

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Like the error says, the variable `style` is not defined before you tried using it at line 37, character 43. It looks like you're trying to use it in a method called `style` that has a param called `feature` -- is there a tutorial or guide you were working from that has something similar? It may be that you missed a line or section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a non-existent `style` variable. You also made some errors for layer order.

I've done [a demo with corrections](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/d0b6fd63c3e57d65b04a3e7dba08f1a8) to make your sample works.
The fix for style is mainly due to changing `stradario_provincialiStyle` to a style then reuse it within the option `style` of `ol.layer.Vector`.

Comment: Hope that I have accepted your answer... Sorry but I'm new here... :(